# Point of studying divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The question is basically, why do we study divergent series (changed the phrasing to do away with the pessimistic tone to the header)?

Are there any topics in any field, not necessarily within mathematics, which have gained significantly from the study of divergent series?

For example, study of the Fibonacci sequence which is divergent, has had impact in many fields, of which examples are computer algorithms and economics.

Comment: Extend a series/integral beyond its domain of convergence $\simeq$ analytic continuation $\simeq$ complex analysis. Another direction is harmonic analysis, distribution theory and functional analysis.

Comment: also there are lots of summation methods (Abel, Cesaro of various orders, complex analytic continuation, and many others) which give divergent series values consistent with convergence - in the sense that if the series converges, the summation method gives same value - and led to very fruitful mathematics like Tauberian theory (and modern proofs of PNT) for example